# How to apply Backend Theme in Magento 2?

Tags: adminhtml, backend, magento2

I have created a new admin theme under app/design/adminhtml. I verified that the new theme gets deployed as well. I am using  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Unlike in the frontend there is not option in the UI to select a backend theme.

How do I tell Magento to apply my custom backend theme?

Comment: Try to refer to this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/120960/23344