# How to change backend admin theme in Magento 2.0.7 +

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, theme

How and what to add to be able to override any of the magento-backend module templates and what is the sequence order of the custom module or theme

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I followed this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96559/23344 and it works like a charm.

Below its step 3 improved.

I created the module in `\app\code\XXX\Backend\` and within the files:

`\app\code\XXX\Backend\registration.php`

```
<?php

 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'XXX_Backend', __DIR__
);
```

`\app\code\XXX\Backend\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="XXX_Backend" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`\app\code\XXX\Backend\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="frontend" xsi:type="string">Magento/luma</item>
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">XXX/backend</item>
            </argument>
         </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Finally run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Now you could extend adminhtml template, i customize `\app\design\adminhtml\XXX\backend\Magento_Sales\templates\items\column\name.phtml` and it works.

Comment: I applied this solution and it works but products thumbnails  is no longer visible

Comment: Which page do you mean?

Comment: What you wrote works great in sense that it is applied, but my custom theme for admin has no generated files. I'm missing files from `/pub/static` after running `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy`. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Is your `pub/static` completely empty?

Comment: was anyone able to create an adminhtml theme following the M2 docs?

Comment: @dchayka I have made composer installable base admin theme for Magento 2.2.2 as I did not see any composer examples out there.
https://github.com/camdixon/magento2-admin-theme

Answer (score 6):

A follow-up to Luca's answer that might help others like who only look to extend the layout:

1. in your newly created app that sets the adminhtml theme, in **etc/module.xml**, you have use:

   > `<module name="Magento_Theme"/>`

as a sequence.

2. you have to have some css file or other static content in **app/design/adminhtml/name/theme/web** `(I placed the _theme.less file in /web/css/source)`. You can inspect the **checkThemesInput** method in `Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand` to find out why.

Comment: +1 for your second point. I was missing this and it will not work without at least something in there. After this you need to do setup:deploy

Comment: For those who want to know how to override adminthml colors and CSS.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121116/magento-2-how-to-override-adminhtml-css

Comment: I have made composer installable base admin theme for Magento 2.2.2 as I did not see any composer examples out there.  This question & answer was of great help!
https://github.com/camdixon/magento2-admin-theme