# How to Override my admin phtml and css file in my theme

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, less-css

How to Override my Admin PHTML, XML and LESS/CSS file in my theme.

Any one have Idea ?

Comment: Create a new admin theme extending form the theme that you Want to override and the change then like we normally  override

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need your theme specific functionality that needs changes in the Admin panel.

Under $MAGENTO_BASE_DIR/app/code, create a Vendor>/Theme> directory. Under that create a view/adminhtml. Underneath you can the create templates directory for your phtml, layout directory for your XML and web directory Less/CSS

Basically

```
app/code/<Vendor>/<Theme>/view/adminhtml/web
app/code/<Vendor>/<Theme>/view/adminhtml/layout
app/code/<Vendor>/<Theme>/view/adminhtml/templates
app/code/<Vendor>/<Theme>/view/adminhtml/ui_component
```

If you are creating a new theme for the Admin, you cal follow the Magento [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html) for creating admin theme

Comment: Which was the better way to override admin PHTML, XML and LESS/CSS.

1. Create new theme OR
2. Create new folder under $MAGENTO_BASE_DIR/app/code,

Comment: That depends on your situation. If I am writing functionality, say for example megamenu and providing configuration options under MegaMenu in AdminHtml specifically for my extension, then I will use the new folder under app/code/Vendor/Theme option.  On the other hand if I am changing the existing admin options, I will go with creating new admin theme and overriding the way we normally override.

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124336/how-to-enable-custom-admin-theme-in-magento-2) to override `adminhtml` theme and this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121116/magento-2-how-to-override-adminhtml-css) to override `css,js` files.